# GROUP BY без групповых функций в MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Какую информацию выдаёт MySQL, если делать `GROUP BY` без групповых функций?

например:

```
id|name|count|date
-------------------------
1 | aa |  1  |null
1 | bb |null |2007-12-12
1 |null|  2  |2015-10-12
```

GROUP BY id

будет здесь какая-нибудь закономерность в выдаче в полях `name`, `count` и `date` или туда попадают случайные значения из выборки?

P.S. тот же PostgreSQL просто выдаст ошибку.

Comment: если быть совсем точном, то строка, которая будет отобрана, конечно, не случайна. но, ввиду того, что по мере внесения изменений в таблицу, будут выдаваться разные строки, то для «простого пользователя» это будет выглядеть именно как «случайно выбранная строка».

Comment: Не только PostgreSql так себя ведет. И MS Sql и Oracle тоже выдадут ошибку потому, что это противоречит стандарту. В MySql же (если не задавать специальных параметров) в данном случае используется некий расширенный стандарт, который позволяет так делать. Считается, что если указанная колонка не перечислена в group by, то все ее значения в пределах группы одинаковы и поэтому не важно из какой именно строки оно будет возвращено.

Comment: В дополнение к комментариям выше - ссылка на документацию: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 2):

При исполнении запроса есть некий порядок обработки строк.
Заданный либо разработчиком, либо на усмотрение оптимизатора.
Так вот будет выдана строка, которая была обработана первой в группе.

Следующий запрос:

```
SELECT *
FROM(
  SELECT *
  FROM(
              SELECT 1 id, 1 OrderBy, 10 value
    UNION ALL SELECT 1 id, 2 OrderBy, 20 value
    UNION ALL SELECT 1 id, 3 OrderBy, 30 value
  )T
  ORDER BY OrderBy
)T
GROUP BY id
```

Вернёт:

```
id OrderBy value
1  1       10
```

Однако такой запрос:

```
SELECT *
FROM(
  SELECT *
  FROM(
              SELECT 1 id, 1 OrderBy, 10 value
    UNION ALL SELECT 1 id, 2 OrderBy, 20 value
    UNION ALL SELECT 1 id, 3 OrderBy, 30 value
  )T
  ORDER BY OrderBy DESC
)T
GROUP BY id
```

Вернёт уже:

```
id OrderBy value
3  3       30
```

Но, повторюсь, сортировку может выбрать оптимизатор какую угодно, поэтому в общем случае, предсказать какую строку "выберет" оптимизатор невозможно.

Т.е. да, теоретически, если задать уникальную сортировку, можно использовать данную особенность MySQL осознанно. Но на свой страх и риск. Поскольку данное поведение не описано в документации и может измениться в будущих версиях MySQL сервера.

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ из комментариев*

Будет выдана случайная строка, если быть совсем точном, то строка, которая будет отобрана, конечно, не случайна. Однако, ввиду того, что по мере внесения изменений в таблицу, будут выдаваться разные строки, то для «простого пользователя» это будет выглядеть именно как «случайно выбранная строка».

Это не типичное поведение для СУБД, так ведет себя пожалуй только MySQL. PostgreSql, MS Sql и Oracle выдадут ошибку потому, что это противоречит стандарту SQL. В MySql же (если не задавать специальных параметров) в данном случае используется некий расширенный стандарт, который позволяет так делать. Считается, что если указанная колонка не перечислена в `GROUP BY`, то все ее значения в пределах группы одинаковы и поэтому не важно из какой именно строки оно будет возвращено.